# React Input Losing Focus in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, input, focus

I am coding in react js.

We have an input form, which has text input.  The text input fires an onChange function that results in a change in state (and thus rendering).

```
var resultJSXcount = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  resultJSXTable.push(
    <tr key= {resultJSXcount++}>
      <td  style = {{"paddingRight": "10px"}} > {i+1}: </td>
      <td  style = {{"paddingRight": "10px"}}> 
        <input 
          type='text' 
          id = {i}
          value = {myArray[i].name}
          onChange = {(event)  => {
            myArray[i].name = event.target.value; 
            this.props.updateState()}}
          />
      <span style={{"color":"red"}} > 
        {this.props.parentState.errorName[i]} 
      </span>
    </tr>
  ); 
}
```

This works perfect in Chrome and Internet Explorer.  In Firefox, you cannot type, because the input loses focus.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this really a focus problem? Have you tried `defaultValue` instead of `value` in your input?

Comment: Yes, it is a focus problem because it works in internet explorer and in chrome.  I tried with defaultValue but it does not impact the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess. It's just a guess, because you do not show everything that is going on.

Your problems come from not understanding how React works. Try this:

- myArray probably comes from state or props. Use setState() to update the contents of myArray instead doing `myArray[i].name = event.target.value;` within onChange. Or if it comes from props, then use redux to update them.
- you probably use props.updateState to trigger rerendering of the component. This should not be necessary if you things described in previous point.

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details.  In some ways we have probably over complicated things.  We are not using props.updateState and are passing the variable through to state using setState(myArray: myArray).  The issue is that instead of updating the input, it appears that in firefox we are deleting and recreating the input, thus losing focus.  Is there anything about firefox that causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!  I found out the problem was in a completely different area of the code.  The above code worked fine.

My error was that when I was applying my styles I had a random focus().  I am not sure why it still worked in Chrome, but crisis averted.

Thanks for the input!